# How to force a height on an html table?

Tags: html, css

Not sure why but this table isn't listening to me. I'm giving it height/max-height of 20px and it's still showing all the rows.

css:

```
table {
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:20px;
    max-height:20px;
}
```

html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>this is a row</td></tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/7demh/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to the table's CSS:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This will make it fill the available horizontal space, so add an explicit width if you want to limit it:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>this is a row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```